# React Components Saved in State of parent wont update, but hardcoded ones would

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state

My problem is that when I hardcode it like this the child will update when its prop changes

```
<parent>
 <child fuz={bar}/>
 <child fuz={bar}/>
<parent>
```

, but when I save these children in the state of the parent like this

```
<parent>
 {parent.stateWhereChildrenAreSavedIn}
</parent>
```

and the state of the children in the state of the parent change, the child is not updated.

What am I doing wrong?
I need to do it like this because the children change on some events and so the list of children has to be updated and is therefore in the state of the parent.

Thanks for the help in Advance :)

Comment: `when I save these children in the state of the parent` can you give an example of how you're setting state? If you're putting elements into state (JSX like `<child />` are elements), that's a really easy way to cause bugs where you render stale data. Your state should just be the minimal data, and then the elements should be created from that data when rendering.

Comment: So when I want to change the data then I should create the elements form the information in the state not saving the hole element?